# ListView in android scroll very slow when they take a short place

Tags: android, performance, listview, scroll

Please, the listview with just 3 textview (there is no image) it was working very fine when it was taking the full screen in height and width. 
and after i have been change it to take the half of screen in height, it became scrolling very slow.

layout for rows in listView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/timer_row">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_row"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/main_title_size"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                 />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/author_row"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="@dimen/main_timer_size"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_below="@id/name_row"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/main_timer_size"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the adapter with the viewholder

```
public class MusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Music> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    MusicAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Music> list) {
        this.list = list;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.music_row, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Music music = (Music) getItem(position);
            viewHolder.title.setText(music.getName());
            viewHolder.author.setText(music.getAuthor());
            viewHolder.timer.setText(music.getTimer());

            return convertView;
        }


        static class ViewHolder{
        TextView title,author,timer;
        ViewHolder(View v)
        {
            this.title = v.findViewById(R.id.name_row);
            this.author = v.findViewById(R.id.author_row);
            this.timer = v.findViewById(R.id.timer_row);
        }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use RecyclerView instead of ListView: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: I realy used the **RecyclerView** before but it the some probleme

Comment: It is hard to debug such kind of problem without actually run the code. You can improve performance by switching to `RecyclerView`, using `ConstraintLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` for list item, make sure your `onBindViewHolder` is lightweight as much as possible (ex: don't use `MediaMetadataRetriever` to get the duration because it is very slow,...). And you can debug your app performance using profiler: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler